# Drop down displaying sideways using Angular Js and jade

Tags: css, angularjs, pug

I want to get data from server and displaying it using **ng-repeat** in jade drop down view. The content is getting displayed but not one by one instead it is displaying side ways. I have spent a lot of time but I couldn't find any solution. 
Please help me with this.
**JADE CODE**

```
li.dropdown.btn.btn-primary.col-10(align='center',style='margin:10px;',ng-repeat='category in vm.categories', ng-if=" category.categoryType !== 'ADDON'")
span
| {{category.categoryName}}
span.caret
ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle='dropdown',ng-repeat='product in vm.products',ng-if='category.categoryName===product.productView.category.categoryName')
li(role='menuitem',ui-sref="app.order.list" , ng-click='vm.show(product)')

  a {{product.productView.productName}}
```

CSS CODE

```
@import "../../../../stylesheets/fy_config";
$imgPath: '../../../imgs';

a {color: black;margin: 5px; text-decoration: none;}

.dropdown-menu li:hover{
visibility: visible;

height:auto;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
margin-top: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
align: center;
position: relative;
top: 0;

float:none;

}
```

Comment: use ng-repeat in <li> element, not <ul>.

Comment: Thanks it worked.. @ddagsan